# How to pin buttons to the bottom iOS7 Autolayout

Tags: ios7, constraints, autolayout, xcode5, pinning

I am having the hardest time positioning items on the scroll view.

[image]

In 3.5" they work fine, in 4" it is higher than I want them to be. 
I want buttons to be tied to the bottom of the screen in both cases. This should be possible with pinning and constraints, I believe. But no matter what I do it works in one but not in the other and wise versa. If I let auto layout add its own constraints it is even worse than if I define some manually.
Had the same problem with 3 buttons at the top but somehow managed it even though I place them under what should be top bar. I am really lost ...

Comment: You have a lot of items with frames that don't match constraints, which might be contributing to your problems. That's what the orange lines in interface builder mean. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19086129/357641

Comment: right but in which order do I need to add constraints? I tried to do Reset to Suggested but have the same problem. I have tried adding Top Space at the top and Buttom greater or equals starting on the bottom, but just can not get it to work, Either text view disappears or buttons on the buttom do.

Comment: So I think the issues is that everything is inside a scroll view? rearanging and moving internal scrollview to the buttom, solves buttons problem but now the scroll view is no where to be found.